# How to store use activity data in Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra, data-modeling, cql

I need to store this data structure in my db:

```
Activity:
  user_id: UUID ( Partition Key )
  created_at: timestamp ( Clustering Key )
  activity_id: UUID ( Clustering Key )
  activity_data: map<string, string>
```

My query to get the data will be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM activities WHERE user_id=SOME-UUID LIMIT 500;
```

From my understanding, When cassandra searches for a row in it's files it will load into memory the entire data even when using LIMIT.

1. Is it true?
2. If so how would I save the data otherwise, when taking into consideration that i want to do only a single query ( from what i know composite partition key will require of me to make multiple queries )
3. How would i store the data if i also need to filter values in my "activity_data" field? is an index on the map field enough?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it merges the data from the disk and respond back to client. Also updated the cache if enabled.Please clarify the other two question.

Comment: 2. How should i save the data if a row can get up to tens or hundreds of gb in the memory without crashing the system?
3. i would like to filter the data in activity_data like so SELECT * FROM activities where user_id=SOME-UUID AND activity_data.activity_name="SOMETHING" LIMIT 500;

Comment: In cassandra you can not save the data while returning it  is a flowing process but should manage your partition or select with limit. you may tune memory also for sometime.